# AJAX request from text file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I've created this rating system with a rating of stars(img) that you click on, 1-5.
Right below it I have added an average counter. This is AJAX so whenever you rate, it will send a call to the text file and update the average number without reloading the page. Yeh yeh, you know the deal.

But what I need help with is to display this statistics all the time. Right now the average count information only appear after you've clicked the rating.

Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#rating-area img').click(function(){
        $('#target').load('ajax.php');
    });
});
</script>

<div id="target">&nbsp;</div>
```

I tried by changing the click function to onload function. But it did not work.

Comment: You mean updating the rating on page load, or every X seconds?

Comment: Every x seconds, sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Winterwind look at the answer below

Comment: This is AJAX so whenever you rate, it will send a call to the text file <- you mean sending a call to the web server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an interval , and calls the file to update the values ​​every second (for example)

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

       setInterval(function(){

              $('#target').load('ajax.php');

       },1000);

   });
 </script>
```

Comment: If the answer has solved your problem "accept it", so help the other users

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the accepted answer to use an interval for this purpose, all you need to do is to call LoadRatings() after page load and after clicking the rate image

```
<script>
   function LoadRatings() {
     $('#target').load('ajax.php');
   }

   $(document).ready(function(){   
     LoadRatings(); 
     $('div#rating-area img').click(loadRatings);   
   });
 </script>
```

Comment: does not want to display the score on the click, but it automatically every few time